# How to pass a values from two different function to third function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to code an exercise in html page with javascript, to calculate the mean of a random array of 6 numbers that generated from `randomArray()` function.
After the first loading of the page and when i click "new problem" button this function recalled to copy the random array in a cell of table.

I write `calcMean` to calculate the mean of the random array which was passed from `randomArray()` , and i make the form stop refreshing the page when i hit Enter key when i enter a input , and return the value of input by searchm()
but the problem now is , i want to take the mean ,maxi,mini and inans , to another function to compare the real answer with the user answer and if the condition is yes , something wrote on a div .
the second problem is , i want to take the mean value from `calcMean()` to show it on the input if i clicked "solution" button which call `solution()` method, what i must pass to the last function to go write.

```
<div >
<form  action="" method="post" name="meanForm"  onsubmit='return false'     id="formmine">

<table width="100%" border="0" >
 <tr>
  <td colspan="3" style="background-color:#06F ;color:#FFF">Answer this   problem</td>
    </tr>
 <tr>
 <td style="color:green; font-size:20px">What is the mean of these numbers </td>
    <td colspan="2" id="numbers">
      </td>
       </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  <tr id="answerANDpic">
    <td height="62" colspan="3"  align="center" > <input name="" type="text"      size="15" maxlength="100" height="50" style=" border: solid #0C0 ; border-width:thin"  id="answer"   onkeydown="searchm(this)"/> </td>
      </tr>
   <tr>
     <td colspan="3"  ><div id ="explain" ></div></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input name="" type="button" id="newEx" style="background-color:green ; color:white"  align ="left" value="New Problem" class="send_feed"  onclick="randomArray(6,0,99)" /></td>
     <td><input name="" type="button"  id="solution" style="background-color:#606 ; color:#FFF  " align="left" class="send_feed" value="Solution"  onclick="solution()"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>



</form>
</div>
```

but in javascript

```
var myNumArray = randomArray(6,0,99);

function random_number(min,max) {
    return (Math.round((max-min) * Math.random() + min));
}

function randomArray(num_elements,min,max) {
   var nums = new Array;

   for (var element=0; element<num_elements; element++) {
       nums[element] = random_number(min,max);
    }

    document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML=nums;
    calcMean(nums);
}




function calcMean(nums) {
    var num=0;
    for (var i=0;i<nums.length;i++) {
        num += parseFloat( nums[i], 6 );
    }
    var divide=num/nums.length;
    var mean=(parseInt(divide,10));
    var maxi = Math.max.apply(Math,nums);
    var mini = Math.min.apply(Math,nums);

    return mean,maxi,mini;
}

function searchm(ele) {
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        // alert(ele.value); // i get the value and put it on alert        

        var inans= ele.value;
        return inans;
    }
}

function comparing(mean,maxi,mini,inans) {
    if(inans==mean){document.getElementById("explain").innerHTML=  "correct"+","+inans+"," +maxi+","+mini;
    }
}

function solution() {
   //some code to take the mean value(realvalue)from calcMean()
   //what is parameter should i pass it when i click on solution button to     pass it this function
}
```

Comment: when you call `calcMean()` at the end of your `randomArray()` function, you should assign the return to a (in your case global) var: `mean = calcMean(nums)` (make sure you define that var first outside of that function). Then you can access it in `solution()` function. But you should refactor your code. Why do you already calculate the mean in function `randomArray`?

Comment: First problem ... `return mean,maxi,mini;` that does **NOT** return what you think, you can only return one value/object from a function

Comment: @Jeff , i didn't calculate the mean inside randomArray()

Comment: @Jeff , 
do you meant that.
var mean;
function randomArray(){....

mean=calcMean();
}
function calcMean(){
.....
return mean;
}

Comment: @OraibAboRob Indeed, you call `calcMean(nums)` right at the end of `randomArray()`!

Comment: @JaromandaX , 
how to take the other values , to use it in comparing () function

Comment: @Jeff what i must do?

Answer (score 0):

Learn `Objects` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

with Objects you can return any kind of data types from your functions

for example

```
function calcMins (nums) {
// ...
  return {mean: mean, maxi: maxi, mini: mini}

var values = calcMins(nums)
var mean = values.mean // and so on
```

at solution() you need to read your `document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML` and run
`calcNums(nums)` from saved numbers. After that you may compare values.mean with your input mean

Not writing full code, cause it's exercise, discover the ways how to use functions, Objects, or Arrays, seems you are familiar with arrays

`return [mean, maxi, mini]` will work, try it too

Comment: thanks alot
if i face a problem , i will ask you ,
ok ?

Comment: ask here, but at first, try to google it and play with code by yourself, it's very important to understand how to use function. Maybe some online courses as codecademy or tutsplus will help you a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can change to something like this.
As others users said, you can't return multiple values, so convert it to an object

```
var valuesReturned = null; // initialize variable

function randomArray(num_elements,min,max) {
   var nums = new Array;

   for (var element=0; element<num_elements; element++) {
       nums[element] = random_number(min,max);
    }

    document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML=nums;
    valuesReturned = calcMean(nums);
}




function calcMean(nums) {
    var num=0;
    for (var i=0;i<nums.length;i++) {
        num += parseFloat( nums[i], 6 );
    }
    var divide=num/nums.length;
    var mean=(parseInt(divide,10));
    var maxi = Math.max.apply(Math,nums);
    var mini = Math.min.apply(Math,nums);

    return {"mean":mean, "maxi": maxi, "mini": mini}; //convert to an object
}

function solution() {
    if(valuesReturned) {
        // make your stuff
        // valuesReturned.mean
        // valuesReturned.mini
        // valuesReturned.maxi
    }
}
```

### EDIt

For `searchm()` function

```
function searchm() {
   if(event.keyCode == 13) {
      var values = calcMean();
      var inans= values.mini;
     return inans;
   }
}
```

Comment: Global variables bad approach for learning function.  It's better for learning to use return values

Comment: what about searchm() function , can i get its value by making it as object ?and put it in valuesRetuernd ?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude , how i get the data from a div element , and store it in an array ?

Comment: very simple: `document.getElementById("element").innerHTML`. `innerHTML` property returns you the content inside `#element`. You can set a custom html asigning a value: `document.getElementById("element").innerHTML = "new text";`

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude thaanxs very much :)

Comment: Accept answer as valid, please

Answer (score 0):

```
 Declare a new array in calcMean function and push all mean , mini , maxi  
 value in new array. And get these value in solution like this :
```

---

```
            var myNumArray = randomArray(6,0,99);
            var numarr=new Array();
            function random_number(min,max) {
                return (Math.round((max-min) * Math.random() + min));
            }

            function randomArray(num_elements,min,max) {
               var nums = new Array;

               for (var element=0; element<num_elements; element++) {
                   nums[element] = random_number(min,max);
                }

                document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML=nums;
               numarr= calcMean(nums);
            }




            function calcMean(nums) {
                var num=0;
                for (var i=0;i<nums.length;i++) {
                    num += parseFloat( nums[i], 6 );
                }
                var divide=num/nums.length;
                var arr=new Array();
                var mean=(parseInt(divide,10));
                var maxi = Math.max.apply(Math,nums);
                var mini = Math.min.apply(Math,nums);
                arr.push(mean);
                arr.push(maxi);
                arr.push(mini);
                return arr;
            }

            function searchm(ele) {
                if(event.keyCode == 13) {
                    // alert(ele.value); // i get the value and put it on alert        

                    var inans= ele.value;
                    return inans;
                }
            }

            function comparing(mean,maxi,mini,inans) {
                if(inans==mean){document.getElementById("explain").innerHTML=  "correct"+","+inans+"," +maxi+","+mini;
                }
            }

            function solution() {
               alert(numarr[0]);   //for mean value
               alert(numarr[1]);    // for maxi
               alert(numarr[2]);   // for maxi
            }
```

Comment: Thanks very much :) 
@shravan